# Image location when loaded by javascript in a rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, project, relative-path, filepath

I have a javascript plugin in my rails project that loads an image this way:

```
    $('.datepicker').after('<img class="datepickericon" src="images/icons/calendar.png" alt="calendar" />');
```

Unfortunately in a rails project this image location will point to a path relative to the view where the javascript is loaded. So the pointed location is something like

```
"admin/images/icons/calendar.png"
```

I know i could change the value of src to something like

```
"../public/images/[etc]/calendar.png"
```

This would work, but it is dependent on the amount of namespaces etc. I don't like to change the code of a plugin every time a use it for different situations.

So what i am looking for is a lasting solution to this image/file location problem when loading something in a (rails) project through javascript. Ofc, no absolute paths or ruby code in my javascript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a relative url. You want:

```
src="/images/icons/calendar.png"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that a forward slash in the beginning of a url replaces the base url, i.e. '/' replaces 'localhost:####'.